# How long can a ASP.net application run for a single request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

We have developed a web application which consumes a web service. The user will upload   data using the application. Uploading one record using web service takes 7 sec. The user will upload approximately 12000 record at a time. So it is taking more time. So can a web application run for more than 5 or 6 hours ?

What are all the factors that i have to consider when deploying this application.

There is also an option to upload the records in bulk, like

```
<Object>
<record>
<value1> 1  </value1>
<value2> asd </value2> 
</record>
<record>
<value1> 2 </value1>
<value2> asd </value2> 
</record>
<record>
<value1> 3 </value1>
<value2> asd </value2> 
</record>
<record>
<value1> 4 </value1>
<value2> asd </value2> 
</record>
</object>
```

but the problem is we need to have the upload status for each record. If there is any data error in onr record the entire upload will be canceled. so we are processing the records one by one.

Please suggest if there is a better way to do this. Also please let me know if you have any questions regarding this issue. thanks.

Regards,
Jebli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. User uploads file.
2. Application takes the file and saves it somewhere.
3. Application runs background thread for processing uploaded file. It can be even processed by external application, which takes file as an input.
4. User immediately receives an answer from server stating that processing has begun.
5. User has access to another page that shows upload progress and reports faulty entries.

End user shouldn't wait more than time that file upload lasts. You don't want users staring at spinning circle for hours:)

Comment: So you mean that back ground process will end if the user clossed the window ?

Comment: No. If users closes browser nothing happens. That doesn't influence processing on server. I just wanted to say that every http request should be quick and if there is additional processing, it should be done in background. You should prepare other page with processing status.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to keep in mind for your current solution is to set the timeout on the server connection high enough.

Apart from that, a better solution would be to let users upload the raw file and do the complete processing server side in a Background Process. Keeping the user informed of the status of that process isn't all to difficult either.